# Gutenberg consume wp-json data and reflect in frontend the content

Tags: javascript, editor, block-editor

I have a custom gutenberg block which is dynamically fetching custom post data via wp-json on edit. How do I persevere the data on save for the fronted?

here is my custom component (**preview.js**) which I include in edit method

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n
const { Component } = wp.element

export default class Preview extends Component {

    state = {
        teachers: false,
    }

    getTeachers = () => {
        const { location } = this.props.attributes

        fetch( `/wp-json/wp/v2/teachers` )
            .then( response => response.json() )
            .then( teachers => {
                this.setState( { teachers: teachers } )
            } )
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getTeachers()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(lastProps, lastStates) {
        if( lastProps.attributes.productID != this.props.attributes.productID ) {
            this.getTeachers()
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { teachers } = this.state

        let wrapper;
        if (teachers) {
            wrapper = teachers.map(function (teacher) {
                return (
                    <div className="wp-block-profiles__element" key={teacher.id}>
                        <div className="wp-block-profiles__image-container">
                            <img className="wp-block-profiles__image" src={ teacher.profile_image.url } alt={ teacher.profile_image.alt } />
                        </div>

                        <h4>{teacher.first_name} {teacher.last_name}</h4>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }

        return (
            !! teachers ? (
                <div className="wp-block-profiles">
                    {wrapper}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <p className="profile-block-message">{ __( 'Loading Profiles...', 'block-profiles' ) }</p>
            )
        )
    }
}
```

and here is where I register my custom block

```
//  Import CSS.
import './style.scss'
import './editor.scss'
import Inspector from './inspect'
import Preview from './preview'

const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const {
    registerBlockType,
} = wp.blocks

const { Fragment } = wp.element

/*
 * @param  {string}   name     Block name.
 * @param  {Object}   settings Block settings.
 * @return {?WPBlock}          The block, if it has been successfully
 *                             registered; otherwise `undefined`.
 */
registerBlockType( 'cgb/profiles-cgb-block', {
    // Block name. Block names must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
    title: __( 'Profiles' ), // Block title.
    icon: 'shield', // Block icon from Dashicons → https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/.
    category: 'custom-category', // Block category — Group blocks together based on common traits E.g. common, formatting, layout widgets, embed.
    keywords: [
        __( 'Profiles' ),
        __( 'CGB' ),
        __( 'teachers'),
    ],
    attributes: {
        teachers: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [],
        },
        locations: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [],
        },
        levels: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [],
        }
    },
    edit: ( props ) => {
        const { attributes, setAttributes, posts } = props
        const { locations, levels, teachers } = attributes

        return [
            <Fragment>
                <Inspector { ...{ attributes, setAttributes } } />

                { !! locations ? (
                    <Preview { ...{ teachers, levels, attributes } } />
                ) : (
                    <p class="profiles-block-message">{ __( 'Please select at least Location to render profiles', 'cgb/block-profiles' ) }</p>
                ) }
            </Fragment>
        ]
    },
    save: ( props ) => {
        return null
    },
} );
```

In this case everything is getting saved in the editor but nothing shows in frontend

Comment: Your save function is empty. Did you use PHP to render the save on the front end? If yes, kindly share that code as well

Comment: Hi, thanks for feedback I did not used any php method in this case, I tought it can be rendered in the same way as in backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are building is called '**Dynamic Block**' and Your block will not work because you haven't added the front end code ( which is the PHP part for dynamic block ). See this [official block code](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/blocks/creating-dynamic-blocks/) there's PHP part as well to save the block and work on the front end.

Here's the official explanation -

> Because it is a dynamic block it also needs a server component. The
>   rendering can be added using the render_callback property when using
>   the register_block_type function.

Although you can use [ServerSideRender](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src/server-side-render) component but it's not recommended.